# Scroll View and View Hierarchies in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in a custom cell in a UITableView. I want to have a UIScrollView so I can display multiple photos horizontally within the custom table cell.

What's the correct way to approach this problem? Does the multiple UIImageViews go on top of the Scroll View? I'm using Storyboards currently but am happy to do programmatically if easier.

Comment: You could subclass a UITableIViewCell, place a subview in this subclass where this subview contains another UITableView. However, you should probably place a new child view controller in each table view cell, this should also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about this scroll view being horizontal, then go for it!
However, I'd avoid having nested vertical scroll views - it creates a confusing UX for the user in my experience.

You can read up about it here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html

With regards as to how to achieve this:

Create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and set up the view how you want. Include a `tableView`. You will need to make a controller for this custom cell, and have it inherit the protocols required for the `tableView`

Comment: So, I created a subclass of UITableViewCell, load up the ScrollView and ImageViews on top of Scroll View. Then what? Do I need to do anything with gesture recognizers?